# Getting exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError

Tags: java, oop, stack-overflow

I am new to Java and OOPs and here is my issue. When I run the below code, I get the

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError.

The problem is in the code were I create an object of `JavaApplication1`.The problem is not occurring for class `App2`. The code works fine if the object `ja` is created inside the run method. Can you explain me why?

```
package javaapplication1;

public class JavaApplication1 {

    int i, k, j;

    class App2 {
        int i = 23;
        int j = 12;
    }

    App2 a2 = new App2();
    JavaApplication1 ja = new JavaApplication1();

    public void run() {
        ja.i = 10;
        a2.i = 26;
        a2.j = 18;
        System.out.println(i + "," + j + "'" + ja.i + "'"
                           + a2.i + "'" + a2.j + "'" + k);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int k = 24;
        JavaApplication1 ja1 = new JavaApplication1();
        ja1.run();
        ja1.i = 18;
        System.out.println(ja1.i + "'" + "'" + k);
    }
}
```

Comment: Every time you construct a `JavaApplication1` instance, you create _another_ instance inside (field `ja =new JavaApplication1();`), and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your class `JavaApplication1` has field `JavaApplication1 ja` which holds another instance of `JavaApplication1` class, which also has its own `ja` field which holds another instance of `JavaApplication1`, and so on and on.

In other words, when you create instance of `JavaApplication1` this instance creates its inner instance of `JavaApplication1` and this inner instance creates another `JavaApplication1` instance, which again creates instance `JavaApplication1`... until stack will be full.

So when you run this code in your main method

```
JavaApplication1 ja1 = new JavaApplication1();
```

something like this happens

```
       +-----------------------------------------------+
ja1 -> | JavaApplication1 instance                     |
       +-----------------------------------------------+
       |                                               |
       |       +------------------------------------+  |
       | ja -> | JavaApplication1 instance          |  |
       |       +------------------------------------+  |
       |       |                                    |  |
       |       |       +-------------------------+  |  |
       |       | ja -> |JavaApplication1 instance|  |  |
       |       |       +-------------------------|  |  |
       |       |       |                         |  |  |
       |       |       | ja -> ....              |  |  |
       |       |       +-------------------------+  |  |
       |       +------------------------------------+  |
       +-----------------------------------------------+
```

Anyway I don't see where `ja` field is ever used, so consider removing it from your code.

Answer (score 2):

I think you end up creating JavaApplication1 objects all the time which cause the stackOverflow exception. You should remove the line with the comment.

```
 App2 a2 = new App2();
 JavaApplication1 ja =new JavaApplication1(); //why do you need this?
 public void run(){
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you can't do something like this:

```
Class Try{
Try try = new Try();
public static void main(String[] arg)
{
Try try1 = new Try();
}
```

The issue with above code is that first the execution will start with your main method(ofcourse in this particular case :) ) then the try1 object will get created and all of the Class fields will get initialized, since you created an object of the same class you are in as a Class Field() it will try to re-initialize the Class fields, ending up in an infinite loop and inevitably the Famous STACK OVERFLOW error!

Now, talking in context of your question:

```
App2 a2 = new App2();
JavaApplication1 ja =new JavaApplication1(); //remove this line, it is causing the SO-error!!!
```

Answer (score 1):

Your class `JavaApplication1` has member `JavaApplication1 ja` initialized in-place. This means that when you create new instance of `JavaApplication1` in `main()` method you call implicit default constructor that calls `new JavaApplication1()` again, and again, and again.

If your want your code to work, first remove line

```
JavaApplication1 ja =new JavaApplication1();
```